# How to set image URL in Stylesheet

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter to build an application. I have placed my images in `assets/images/images/myimage.jpg` I know how to call this from PHP file. I write..

`<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/images/images/myimage.jpg`

but I'm unable to understand how to do this in a stylesheet, I tried to write the following but its not getting the image

```
background:url(../assets/images/images/header-bg.jpg) no-repeat center top;
```

The `Asset` folder is in the base directory along with `application,system and user_guide` folder.

Comment: if you have separate css stylesheet file you should go for writing your class on view style tags.or try to set the property using javascript.

Comment: Try something like this: `background:url(../images/images/header-bg.jpg) no-repeat center top;`

Comment: If your directory is like this: `assets/css/style.css` it will work.

Comment: where is you .css file placed?

Comment: If it's in `css/css` like your `images` folder ,then try `../../images/images.header-bg.jpg`.

Comment: Where is your CSS files? That will depend how you locate the background image.

Comment: try this - background:url(/assets/images/images/header-bg.jpg) no-repeat center top;

Comment: css file is in `assets/css/css/style.css`

Comment: use background:url(../../images/images/header-bg.jpg)

Comment: @user3480644 Put your css text in a separate php file and sets it header to text-css. Then call that php file in your link attribute. This method is referred as dynamic css content

Comment: If you use url('/assets/images/images/myimage.jpg') you set the path absolute and not relative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One Sample Example ;
Try like this..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body 
{
background-image:url('image.jpg');
background-color:#cccccc;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
</body>

</html>
```